# Перенаправление гостя на страницу авторизации Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, auth

Нужно при загрузке любого контроллера или модуля проверять, если юзер является гостем, отправлять его на `yii.local/auth` (на страницу авторизации)

Может есть фильтры некие, которые происходят при инициализации приложения? Как это проверить, реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создаем компонент, например `Init`. У компонентов можно определить метод `init`, он будет вызываться перед каждым экшном любого контроллера.
В нем определяем, если не гость, то редирект на страницу логина (либо другой урл, какой вам надо)

```
namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Url;

class Init extends \yii\base\Component  {

    public function init() {
        if (\Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest &&
            \Yii::$app->getRequest()->url !== Url::to(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl)
        ) {
            \Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl);
        }

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Далее компонент нужно обязательно добавить в конфиг

```
'components' => [
    'Init'=>[
        'class'=>'app\components\Init'
     ],
     //другие компоненты
]
```

Добавить инициализацию компонента сразу при загрузке (тоже пишется в конфиге)

```
'bootstrap' => ['log','Init'],
```

P.S. Если не собираетесь юзать тут евенты или бихейворы то вместо `\yii\base\Component` можно использовать `\yii\base\Object`

Comment: спасибо большое! четко и доступно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Не подскажете? Создал в папке components файл `Init.php` с указанным в примере содержимым. В папке config в файле `web.php` добавил как в примере в конфиг и в bootstrap. Но выводит ошибку `Unknown bootstrapping component ID: Init`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский https://i.imgur.com/KYpBBSb.png

Comment: @n.osennij не знаю.давно был подобный баг у yii относительно gii, может относительно компонентов в bootstrap тоже в какой-нибудь версии есть. Можно самую свежую новую версию поставить посмотреть. Но я к сожалению подсказать не могу.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский очень странно, но напечатал всё вручную (не копируя), и всё заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: @n.osennij вот только хотел написать об этом..... что бывает, что когда копируешь с SO копируется почему-то utf-8 с BOM, то есть добавляются символы незаметные глазу) несколько раз так было с JS скриптами, обнаруживал только в консоли.... а с пхп не помню где можно увидеть