# Автоматический редирект для не авторизированного пользователя во всех контроллерах

Tags: php, yii2, framework

Всем привет!
Делаю личный кабинет на yii2, и сразу возникла проблема авторизации.
Нужно перенапровлять гостевого пользователя на страницу авторизации, в нескольких контроллерах, т.к. эти контроллеры должны быть НЕ доступны гостю.
Можно конечно в каждом контроллере и в каждом экшене выполнять проверку, но это же не тру.
Я уверен что в yii есть возможность выполнить проверку в каком то одном методе который загружается перед экшенами. Но вопрос, в каком?

p.s. yii только начал изучать, поэтому многим, вопрос может показаться нубским.

Comment: Вот готовое решение, которое я уже тут описывал http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468788/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-yii2/468801#468801   .........правда тут для всех контроллеров....гостя всегда на авторизацию

Answer (score 4):

В каждом экшене проверку, разумеется, делать не нужно. Для этого существует [AccessControl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html).

Внутри контроллера можно сделать так:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],

                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

и тогда гостям вход будет запрещен.

Если же вы хотите более глобального решения проблемы, без наследования и создания отдельных компонентов ее можно решить так:

```
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => ['login'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function () {
        return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
    },
],
```

Данный код нужно поместить в конфиг приложения, он будет выполняться перед каждым запросом. При желании его можно модифицировать под свои конкретные нужды.

На этот вопрос я ранее отвечал на английском SO [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067849/yii2-require-all-controller-and-action-to-login).

Обратите внимание, что в последнем случае не должно быть экшенов с названием `login` в контроллерах, кроме `SiteController`.