# как создать сообщение в ответ на неудачную попытку аутентификации в Yii2?

Tags: yii2, аутентификация

Необходимо, чтобы страница аутентификации http://localhost:8080/index.php?r=site%2Flogin отвечала сообщением об отсутствии учетной записи, если ее нет среди учтенных. Как это сделать грамотно?

Все учетные записи пока - встроенные в Yii2 (admin, demo), т.е. без базы данных. С ними и будет сверяться ввод. Файлы User.php, LoginForm.php и views/site/login.php - без принципиальных изменений.

models/LoginForm.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property-read User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true; // соответствующий чекбокс 'views/site/login.php' удален за ненадобностью

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],// соответствующий чекбокс 'views/site/login.php' удален за ненадобностью
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
            ['username', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid username.');
                return;
            }
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

views/site/login.php:

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model app\models\LoginForm */

use yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm;
use yii\bootstrap4\Html;

$this->title = 'Аутентификация пользователя';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-login">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>Please fill out the following fields to login:</p>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'login-form',
        'layout' => 'horizontal',
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 col-form-label'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true])->label('Login')  ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

     <!--   <?/*= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox([
            'template' => "<div class=\"offset-lg-1 col-lg-3 custom-control custom-checkbox\">{input} {label}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
        ]) */?>-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-11">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Войти', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    <div class="offset-lg-1" style="color:#999;">
        You may login with <strong>admin/admin</strong> or <strong>demo/demo</strong>.<br>
        To modify the username/password, please check out the code <code>app\models\User::$users</code>.
    </div>
</div>
```

models/User.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

class User extends \yii\base\BaseObject implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;

    private static $users = [
        '100' => [
            'id' => '100',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'authKey' => 'test100key',
            'accessToken' => '100-token',
        ],
        '101' => [
            'id' => '101',
            'username' => 'demo',
            'password' => 'demo',
            'authKey' => 'test101key',
            'accessToken' => '101-token',
        ],
    ];


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if (strcasecmp($user['username'], $username) === 0) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === $password;
    }
}
```

вопрос не является дубликатом предложенному в комментах - достаточно сравнить заголовки топиков

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перенаправление гостя на страницу авторизации Yii2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468788/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-yii2)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет. не дубликат. вы же знаете как ответить по теме топика - не поленитесь. кстати, вопрос, аналогичный упомянутому вами, у меня решился добавлением нескольких строк в public function behaviors() контроллера:
```{ return [ 'access' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(), 'rules' => [
                    [ 'allow' => true, 'roles' => ['@'], ], ],], ];}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В метод findByUsername добавь после foreach Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "Пользователь не найден.");

В шаблоне производишь session->getFlash('error'); ?>

Comment: Евгений, где и в каком шаблоне добавить строчку `session->getFlash('error'); ?>` ? 
как должен выглядеть метод `findByUsername`? в таком виде:
   `public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if (strcasecmp($user['username'], $username) === 0) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "Пользователь не найден.");
        return null;
    }` он производит ошибку: `Class "app\models\Yii" not found`

Comment: Class "app\models\Yii" not found - добавь use Yii;

Comment: findByUsername - да, в таком виде. Выводиш сообщение в том месте, где тебе это нужно, например в форме. Или главном шаблоне приложения. If(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('error')) { echo Yii::$app->session->getFlash('error'); }

Comment: странное дело - и без фразы с getFlash('error') сообщение появляется на странице авторизации. хотя метода getFlash нет нигде в проекте. но если ее не вставить в какое-нибудь неподходящее место, то, похоже, работает. спасибо

Comment: Он по умолчанию в шаблон вписан

Comment: Евгений, а как то же сообщение выводить не стандартным Yii-флэшем, а в модальном окне?

Comment: Я обычно использую Toastr. Выглядит красиво, есть разные варианты дизайна. Если я правильно тебя понял. Можно сделать js функцию, подгружать ее автоматически при загрузке страницы, которая будет проверять записано ли флеш сообщение  об ошибке в сессии, и если есть открывать модальное окно. $('#logoutModal').modal('show');

Comment: я имел в виду обычные уведомления от браузера, в верхней части страницы, пока не нажмешь кнопку работать со страницей нельзя. alert JS их вызывает также

Comment: Смотри. Как вариант. В php выполняешь проверку Yii флеш сообщение. Методом hasFlash. Результат помещаешь в переменную.(результат будет true или false). Передаешь эту переменную в js скрипт и средствами js открываешь модальное окно с текстом ошибки. ($('#Modal').modal('show'); ). Естественно модальное окно нужно добавить в шаблон. Главное скрипт подгоужай в конце. POS_LOAD или POS_READY